# Center UITextField When Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c

Any idea why only the first conditional will work and not the others. self.businessField is the only one that will work. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.businessField)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        //set Y according to keyBoard height
        [mainScroll2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,-40.0,320.0,460.0)];
        [self->mainScroll2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1000)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else if(textField == self.memoField) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
        //set Y according to keyBoard height
        [mainScroll2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,10.0,320.0,460.0)];
        [self->mainScroll2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1000)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        NSLog(@"Memo");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"else");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate for the other text fields?

Comment: Thank you very much. I set the delegates but copy and pasted the delegate statement from the self.businessField and forgot to rename them correctly. It works now.